# Determine what event ajax call is coming from

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Limited ajax event knowledge from my side here. I have a site where I have 2 CGridView on the same CJuiDialog modal. You have 2 inputs to filter the results that will appear in the CGridView's and I can see once I change what to search for an ajax call is made(Chrome dev tools)

My bug is that some event handlers are added to this input search so that there are more than just the one ajax call that is made if I focus away after typing a value to search for.

I expect to just remove the event handlers if I can figure out what they are... maybe just `$("#myinput").undeligate()` in javasctipt and call it good.

Problem is that this is not working. I am using jQuery 1.7.1 and the site is on a secure login so I cannot paste a link to the page here. From what I am reading `.off()` is a jQuery 3 so I have to use `.undeligate()`

Is there a way to determine what events are added to the search input and just undeligate() them?

Comment: [`undelegate`](https://api.jquery.com/undelegate/) you mean?

Comment: As a good start I recommend to get familiar with bubbling and capturing in JavaScript: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#capturing - in this article you can see how to find root event, and how to stop propagation of events

Comment: Yes, undelegate ....... typo on my part.